# How to use StringArray in java

Tags: java, jsp

I've been using Java to create a web service. It is a forum and I use a database for storing topics, comments and replies. 
When retrieving the replies/comments from the server, I store them in an `ArrayList<String[]>` where each String[] holds the text and the ID of the comment/topic it is related to. However when I receive it on the client side I am forced to accept it as a `List<StringArray>` object. All other posts only refer to the normal `String[]`. Could someone please explain how to use a `StringArray` (not `String[]`).

Comment: Or you looking for something of this kind  "Collection<String> c=new ArrayList<String>();"

Comment: What is a `StringArray` if it is not the same as a `String[]` ??

Comment: I have no idea what the StringArray object is. everywhere i look it just refers to String[]

Comment: Did you mean the org.jibx.util.StringArray ?

Comment: It shouldn't be a List<String[]>, nor List<StringArray> (whatever that can be). It should be a List<Comment>, where Comment would have a field `id` and a field `text`(and whatever other field, of whatever type you want. Let's say you want to store the postDate, that should be stored as a Date or Instant, not as a String. Java is an OO object. Use objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there is no "StringArray" datatype in java. 
Also java does not provide any class called "StringArray" similar to StringBuilder/StringBuffer by default.

So then what could be "StringArray" ? It is most definitely one of the below

1. User defined class created by somebody in your project.
2. A class provided by a third party library/toolset you project is using.

So you should first find out if it a user defined class or else what package is providing "StringArray" class and then try to understand how it works.

Going by the information you have provided "Map" seems like a better alternative on server/client side.

A Quick google search shows many third party libraries providing "StringArray" class.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jibx/jibx-bind/1.2.4.5/org/jibx/util/StringArray.java#StringArray.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29

https://uima.apache.org/downloads/releaseDocs/2.3.0-incubating/docs/api/org/apache/uima/jcas/cas/StringArray.html

https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/StringArray.html

Answer (score 0):

**A String array in Java is written as String[].** You make an instance of it like that:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[10]; //Entries 0 - 9
```

But in your case I would recommend to use an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (if you have to save the ID with it).